# How to perform edits to a draft object using Immer.js after promise has resolved without using async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, immer.js

I'm trying to make edits to a draft object from Immer that depend on a promise resolving. I understand how to do this with `async`/`await` syntax, (see below)

```js
import produce from 'immer';

Promise.resolve({ eggs: 0 }).then(
  produce(async (eggCounter) => { const n = (await 5); eggCounter.eggs += n; })
).then(console.log)
```

but when I attempt to translate this into using the explicit `Promise` API, it does not work:

```js
import produce from 'immer';

Promise.resolve({ eggs: 0 }).then(
  produce((eggCounter) => { Promise.resolve(5).then((n) => eggCounter.eggs += n) })
).then(console.log)
```

The above generates the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: illegal operation attempted on a revoked proxy`.

How can I modify the second sample so that it is (sufficiently) equivalent to the first?

Comment: What are you `await`ing a number?

Comment: It’s just an example. In the real situation, it’s a promise coming from an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return a promise for `produce` callback function:

In-line version

```
Promise.resolve({ eggs: 0 }).then(
  produce((eggCounter) => Promise.resolve(5).then((n) => { eggCounter.eggs += n; }))
).then(console.log)
```

Clear version

```
Promise.resolve({ eggs: 0 }).then(
  produce((eggCounter) => {
    return Promise.resolve(5).then((n) => {
      eggCounter.eggs += n;
    });
  })
).then(console.log);
```

Comment: This is correct, though an important _other_ detail that I missed is that the function passed to the `then` call inside the `produce` callback must not return a value (otherwise immer complains that you're augmenting the draft _and_ returning a value.